# Hosting pro myself "all.min.css" works but "light.min.css" is not working, only showing links like "url(../webfonts/fa-light-300.eot)"

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am hosting FontAwesome Pro myself, when I go to "http://localhost:3001/css/all.min.css" I can use `class="fal fa-pencil"` fine.

When I try to use font awesome light I see nothing. I go to "http://localhost:3001/css/light.min.css" all I see is

```
 * Font Awesome Pro 5.10.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
 * License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License)
 */
@font-face{font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Pro";font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:auto;src:url(../webfonts/fa-light-300.eot);src:url(../webfonts/fa-light-300.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../webfonts/fa-light-300.woff2) format("woff2"),url(../webfonts/fa-light-300.woff) format("woff"),url(../webfonts/fa-light-300.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../webfonts/fa-light-300.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")}.fal{font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Pro";font-weight:300}
```

How am I supposed to use just the font awesome light.min.css file, Id rather not import the whole all.min.css file

Answer (score 0):

For the solid, brand, regular files using fab, fas, far icon specific names.so u have to use font awesome min CSS or all min CSS. You have to use all.min.css because of light.min.css not there in font awesome downloaded CSS folder